# XMLHttpRequest not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

The following code I am using to dynamically update the TextArea element in my HTML every 2 seconds without reloading the page. However, the `alert(request.readystate)` is returning undefined instead of a number 1-4. When I tried `if(request) alert("Request object")` it alerts the user "Request object" as expected. I have no clue why this isn't working and I have been trying to figure this out for hours!

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function init(){
      var url="http://www.suchandsuch.net/ChatBowl/text.txt";
      var request= new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("POST",url,true);
      alert(request.readystate);
      request.onload= function(){
        if (request.readystate ==4 && request.status == 200){
          document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML=request.responseText;
        }  
      }
        request.send(null);

     }


    var int=self. setInterval('init()', 2000);

  </script>
```

I appreciated any help.

Comment: is the url you are requesting outside of your domain?

Comment: Also, you should use a GET for that command, to comply with HTML standards

Comment: you really need to make sure everything is in the right case: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#The_onreadystatechange_event_listener

Comment: URL is in my own domain. Switched to GET. Still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive and you typed the readyState wrong:

**readyState** not **readystate**

[MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms534361.aspx)

And the callback function should be assigned to `onreadystatechange`:

```
var url="http://www.suchandsuch.net/ChatBowl/text.txt";
var request= new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    alert(request.readyState + " " + request.status);
    if (request.readyState ==4 && request.status == 200)
          document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML=request.responseText;
    };

request.open("POST", url, true);
alert(request.readyState);
```

request.send();

Comment: @user1190419. what exactly doesn't work? try put alert inside the callback function, I added the alert to the callback.

Comment: @user1190419. Are you sure the id is `textarea`?

Comment: change the `id` to be `foo`. You had problems with that id... you wrote `text area` not `textarea`

Comment: O.K. i figured it out. I forgot to change the readystate to readyState in the if statement.... dunce move. Thanks SOO much!

Answer (score 0):

maybe instead of

```
request.onload= function(){
```

try

```
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
```

Comment: It's true, but the problem is the case sensitive, see my answer.

Comment: @gdoron +1 yup yours is more complete too